# How can I wrap text inside input not text area..?

Tags: javascript, css

I want text not to disappear like this :

[image]

How can I make it to go under to wrap somehow I tried things like

```
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
```

But none of this does not work, anyone help..?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? Then it is easier to help you

Comment: you cannot ....

Comment: That's exactly what a `<textarea>` is for.

Comment: think this through... why would you ask the user to type something into an input field and not let them see what they're typing after a certain point.. that's bad ux. please don't..

Comment: I am using input and it works fine, but I want it to be responsive and when I make it smaller like for mobiles the input is smaller..

Comment: You cannot wrap inside input field. I'd suggest you to use a textarea and apply styles to mimic the style of your input field. You can also disable the `resize` attribute on the textarea. You can dynamically set the height of the textarea on `input event` if you want it to look more like an input https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/czgrf

Answer (score 1):

An input field will not allow you to wrap the input in it. 
The textarea element, even though you don't want to use it, is the element that should be used in this situation.

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="20">
A textarea will allow you to wrap content.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Though this may be a correct way to do this, OP said they didn't want textarea.

Comment: I will up-vote this answer. This is really the best way to do this.